# How to Append to SQL variable and display in Accordion

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, accordion

I'm using accordion for PHP and it uses a string to separate out the multiple accordion instances. In the past I've appended something inside the database or created a separate database and exploded the result in order to have the same string for multiple accordion instances.

What I'm trying to do is concatenate maint_ on my $name result and then use explode to separate it back out that way my name's table in my database won't have duplicate entries. When I run my code now it breaks at the $row["name"] and doesn't continue thus giving me a blank page.

Additional Information: If I remove name from the query the webpage loads however I don't have my additional accordions working because they have no string to populate. I can run

```
 SELECT name,sch_off,sch_on,description FROM applications,systemmaintenance WHERE   
 systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id ORDER BY sch_off;
```

and the webpage will load however accordion has duplicate entries in the name field and causes multiple accordion errors such as duplicate entries and data doesn't go to the correct accordion instance.

SQL Query:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('maint_', name) AS name, sch_on, sch_off, description FROM 
 systemmaintenance LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = 
 applications.pk_app_id ORDER BY sch_off;
```

My PHP Code:

```
 <div id="mainttitle"> <div id="alert">Scheduled Maintenance</div> </div>
   <div id="center">
     <div id="maintcontents">
 <?php
// Query for Maintenance Section
$maintenance = "";
$maintstmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT name, sch_on, sch_off, description FROM 
    systemmaintenance LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON systemmaintenance.fk_app_id =  
    applications.pk_app_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY sch_off;');

    $maintstmt->execute();
while ($row = $maintstmt->fetch()){?>
      <a href='#' data-reveal-id="<?php echo $row["name"] ?>" data-animation="none">
  <div class="grid_3">
        <div id="bluebox">
      <div id="contexttitle"><?php list($blah,$name) = explode('_',$row["name"]); 
           echo $name;?>
           <span style="float:right;"></div></span>
        <div id="maintaccesssubmenu">Sch. Time Off:<?php echo $row["sch_off"]; ?> 
        <br />
Sch. Time On:<?php echo $row["sch_on"]; ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </a>

 <div id="<?php echo $row["name"];?>" class='reveal-modal'>
   <div id="reveal"> 
   <h1><?php echo $name; ?> <br /> <div id="revealreason">Scheduled Off Time: <?php echo 
   $row["sch_off"]; ?></div></h1>
     <div class="accordion">
  <h3><a href=""><?php echo $row["sch_off"]; ?> till <?php echo $row["sch_on"]; ?>
      </a></h3>
        <div><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php }  ?>                       
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to make that easy to read I hope I did so. As always a huge thanks to the Stack Overflow community without ya'll I wouldn't be where I am today (still a newb but slowly getting there).

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: When I run my php and it looks for the $name variable it won't go past that thus resulting in all the code after it not running. I apologize should had explained that better. I'm not very good at doing catch's to get the correct errors need to study up on that. If I remove the name completely from the query it works but I obviously don't get what I need for the other accordion instances. I also can put SELECT name,sch_off,sch_on,description FROM applications,systemmaintenance WHERE systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = applications.pk_app_id ORDER BY sch_off; and it runs but accordion has duplicate

Comment: entries. I'll edit the question above to reflect this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using PDO, Try a GROUP BY hoping that you are trying to check against the maintenance field

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('maint_', name) AS name, sch_on, sch_off, description FROM 
 systemmaintenance LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = 
 applications.pk_app_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY sch_off;
```

But if you have duplicate names say 'ALPHA' 3 times then you will get name AS "maint_ALPHA,maint_ALPHA,maint_ALPHA".

Also instead of

```
 while ($row = $maintstmt->fetch()){
```

and

```
 $maintstmt->execute(array('maintenance' => $maintenance));
```

Try

```
while ($row = $maintstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

and

```
 $maintstmt->execute();
```

Comment: Didn't work, same result as before (nothing after it ask for $name is loading). I am using PDO but don't know how to do check's quite yet. I'll only have two entries for the names. If it helps I'll have the name in the left column and in the right column of my webpage.

Comment: Won't let me edit my previous comment for some reason but I removed your WHERE maintenance = ? it was giving me a SQL error and I don't need it as anything listed under the systemmaintenance table will show (have that as designed). Anyways worked for SQL but not on webpage.

Comment: see my updated answer, then try $maintstmt->execute();

Comment: Ok tried that I put it in a catch exception and it doesn't even show me anything back. But it's still not loading correctly it works fine on the SQL side just not loading correctly for PHP.                       SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('maint_', name) AS name, sch_on, sch_off, description FROM 
 systemmaintenance LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = 
 applications.pk_app_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY sch_off;

Comment: pass PDO::FETCH_ASSOC in fetch statement

Comment: Same results, not working. If I remove the GROUP_CONCAT and just have name it runs correctly but I still don't get the right results. Just wanted to let you know.       $maintstmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT name, sch_on, sch_off, description FROM 
 systemmaintenance LEFT OUTER JOIN applications ON systemmaintenance.fk_app_id = 
 applications.pk_app_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY sch_off;');
           $maintstmt->execute();
       
       while ($row = $maintstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

Comment: I just added the code for the entire page wondering if there is a mistake somewhere else in it. I'm so sorry for taking up so much time and thanks again for all of your help so far. The code in the Question allows the webpage to load but doesn't give me my maint_ in front of the $name variable so I can explode it later. I've tried everything Nouphal has suggested so far.